# Can one "consume cultural materials"?

Tags: word-choice

In my essay, I wrote "can communicate and consume cultural materials (e.g., books and newspapers) in French". By "consume", I mean "read, watch, and listen to materials in a language". Does that sound natural in my sentence? If not, please suggest suitable modifications.

I'm not sure whether I actually saw this kind of usage somewhere or my memory is just faulty.

Thanks!

Comment: Yep that's fine.

Comment: To me, "consume" sounds like you are eating the books and newspapers.

Comment: *Cultural materials* would include things with no linguistic component, such as visual art. "Consuming a painting in French" probably doesn't make much sense.

Comment: You read and speak French? Or . . .?

Comment: @DJClayworth sorry I mistyped the title. Corrected.

Comment: @Xanne By "consume", I mean I read books, watch movies and listen to music in French.

Comment: It’s okay, but it sounds clumsy, like something out of a sociology textbook. The *production* and *consumption* of a *cultural object* does not correspond to the intellectual tasks of *writing a book* and *reading a book*. The generality robs your work of force.